# Questions about what is $E[X \mid c]$

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value

> Let $Y$ be a constant RV that equals $7$ with probability one.
>
> **Q1:** Is it true that $E[X \mid Y] = E[X]$?
>
> **Q2:** Is $E[X \mid Y]$ a random variable?
>
> **Q3:** What is $E[Y \mid X]$?

My attempt:

For the first question I believe the answer is yes. Knowing $Y=7$ does not tell you anything about $X$ therefore $E[X|Y] = E[X]$ so $E[X \mid c] = E[X]$.

For the second question I believe the answer is yes, $E[X \mid c]$ is a constant RV.

The third question is $E[c \mid X] = c$ again due to independence.

Am I on the right track for all three questions? Thanks.

Comment: You don't define $X$. What is $X$?

Comment: You are on the right track.  I would disagree somewhat with the reason for the third.  The expectation for a constant is the constant - independence is irrelevant.

Comment: @BlackMath $X$ can be any "typical" RV where by "typical" I mean whatever $X$ they use when they say $E[X+c] = E[X]+c$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thanks for your help, I was having problems finding material for $E[X|c]$. Your comment on the third question makes sense.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Justification of answer of OP on Q3: In general if $Y$ and $X$ are independent then $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]=\mathbb EY$. This can be applied here, because $Y$ is constant a.s. and is consequently independent wrt to $X$.

Comment: @rdhab You misunderstood my point.  All I said was that in the case of Q3 it was not necessary to invoke independence, since c is a constant.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Okay. Then I gave a too heavy load to the word "disagree" that you used. If I understand correctly now  then you only meant to say that things could be done more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1** Correct.

Prescribing $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ by $\omega\mapsto\mathbb EX$ it is guaranteed that it is a random variable that is measurable wrt $\sigma(Y)$.

This because the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a constant random variable is $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ hence is subset of any $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

Next to that for every Borel set $B$ we must check that $$\int_{\{Y\in B\}}\mathbb EX\;\mathsf P(d\omega)=\int_{\{Y\in B\}}X(\omega)\mathsf P(d\omega)$$

For this we discern two situations: $7\in B$ and $7\notin B$.

If $7\in B$ then $P(\{Y\in B\})=1$ and both sides take value $\mathbb EX$ and if $7\notin B$ then $P(\{Y\in B\})=0$ and both sides take value $0$.

**Q2** Correct.

**Q3** Correct

Prescribing $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]$ by $\omega\mapsto7$ it is again guaranteed that it is a random variable that is measurable wrt $\sigma(X)$

Now it must be checked that for every Borel set $B$ we have: $$\int_{\{X\in B\}}7\;\mathsf P(d\omega)=\int_{\{X\in B\}}Y(\omega)\mathsf P(d\omega)$$which is a direct consequence of $Y=7$ a.s.

More generally: if $X,Y$ are independent random variables then $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]=\mathbb EY$.

This can be applied here (as you did) because a random variable that is constant a.s. is independent wrt to any random variable defined on the same probability space.

---

P.S. In general there are more than one choices for $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$, but it is enough to find a random variable that satisfies specific conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I know my question was a very basic one but building my understanding for these trivial cases gives me better confidence to tackle more complex problems... I need to put more time into the measure theory part of probability but I can somewhat follow your reasoning... thanks!!

Comment: @HJ_beginner you are very welcome.